# How to either delete an Algolia index/database or clear it?

Tags: algolia

How can we remove all the indexes/database or clear it.
I need to remove all the records. Is it possible from the dashboard ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible from the dashboard.

- Go to "Indices" along the left hand side, then
- Choose the index that you want to delete from the dropdown next to the word Index.
- Along the right hand side of the screen, you'll have a few options to "Manage current index." One of them will allow you to delete the index in question.

Comment: Aha, I had to enter the index name manually. I didn't see that.